# Double Height of Selected Row in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Aloha,

i've got a ListView in my XAML Code and a Grid inside it.

Now there is a snippet of code from my collegue, i need to complete.
The target is, to double the height of the selected Row. The following Snipped double the height of the FIRST row, but not the selected.

```
<Grid.Style>
 <Style TargetType="Grid">
  <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="60"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Grid" Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="120"/>
    </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

What do i have to change, that the selected object is that one, that will have the double height? I'm working with xamarin / xamarin forms UWP / Android.

Additional Info: I have to work in MVVM pattern. So i should avoid using traditional events.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the height of **ViewCell** in runtime . You can call `cell.ForceUpdateSize();` to update the cell's size .

So we use an `TriggerAction` to change this value, and tell the ViewCell to update its size.

```
public class ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    public int HeighRequest { set; get; }

    public ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction() : base()
    {

    }
    protected override void Invoke(VisualElement sender)
    {
        var parent = sender.Parent;
        while (parent != null && !(parent is ViewCell))
        {
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
        if (parent is ViewCell cell)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                sender.HeightRequest = HeighRequest;
                cell.ForceUpdateSize();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

#### in xaml

```
<ListView  HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItems,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

```
<Grid.Style>
   <Style TargetType="Grid">
      <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="60"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Grid" Binding="{Binding IsCheck}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <local:ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction HeighRequest="120" />
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <local:ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction HeighRequest="60" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

#### in Code Behind

**ViewMode**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model> MyItems { get; set; }

    private Model selectItems;
    public Model SelectItems
    {
        get
        {
            return selectItems;
        }

        set
        {
            if (selectItems != value)
            {

                selectItems = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                foreach(Model model in MyItems)
                {
                    if(selectItems==model)
                    {
                        model.IsCheck = !model.IsCheck;                         
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SelectItems = null;

        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<Model>() {

            new Model(){ IsCheck=false},
            new Model(){ IsCheck=false},
            new Model(){ IsCheck=false},
            new Model(){ IsCheck=false},
            new Model(){ IsCheck=false},
            new Model(){ IsCheck=false},
            new Model(){ IsCheck=false},



        };

 }
```

**Model**

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }



    private bool isCheck;
    public bool IsCheck
    {
        get
        {
            return isCheck;
        }

        set
        {
            if (isCheck != value)
            {
                isCheck = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private double height;
    public double Height
    {
        get
        {
            return height;
        }

        set
        {
            if (height != value)
            {
                height = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```