# Dynamically hiding Xamarin Forms ListView item and setting the height of invisible item to 0 not working on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, listviewitem

In a Xamarin Forms ListView, a StackLayout is placed in a ViewCell. The following trigger is used to set the StackLayout's height and margin to 0 so that there is no gap in the ListView.

```
<StackLayout.Triggers>
    <Trigger TargetType="StackLayout" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    </Trigger>
</StackLayout.Triggers>
```

The code works perfectly on Android. But there are still gaps on iOS.

Normally calling ViewCell.ForceUpdateSize on a tapping event can help resolve such an issue. But we need to do it grammatically. So I tried to create a CustomViewCell but it doesn't help.

```
public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
{
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        var viewModel = (tecommobile.ViewModels.Input)BindingContext;
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == "IsVisible")
                {
                    //ForceUpdateSize(); crashes, the possible cause could be the height of the StackLayout is already set to 0. The test shows that the tapped event doesn't fire if the height is 0.
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Please advise a solution or any workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use an **TriggerAction** to change this value, and tell the **ViewCell** to update its size.

```
public class ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    public double HeighRequest { set; get; }  // you could set it as bindable property if you want to binding its value in runtime

    public Thickness CustomMargin { set; get; }

    public ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction() : base()
    {

    }
    protected override void Invoke(VisualElement sender)
    {

        var parent = sender.Parent;
        while (parent != null && !(parent is ViewCell))
        {
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
        if (parent is ViewCell cell)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var view = sender as View;
                view.HeightRequest = HeighRequest;
                view.Margin = CustomMargin;
                cell.ForceUpdateSize();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout.Style>
   <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
       <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="xxx"/> //default height
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding xxx}"  Value="False">  /// xxx here is the property which binding to the IsVisible of stacklayout
                   <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <local:ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction HeighRequest="0.01" CustomMargin="0"/>
                   </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                   <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <local:ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction HeighRequest="xxx" CustomMargin="xxx"/> // set the default value of height and margin here
                   </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
          </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</StackLayout.Style>
```

And don't forget to set `HasUnevenRows="True"` of listview.

Comment: Hi Lucas, Thanks for your code. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Binding', or mismatching type between value and property. in Binding="IsVisible" in <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="IsVisible" Value="False">

Comment: Check my update answer , binding the xxx(isvisible) to the Trigger.

Comment: I changed to Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference viewCellStackLayout}, Path=IsVisible}". then it compiles. Is it correct?

Comment: Post your full code , or you would better share your sample .

Comment: Here is a similar issue which you can have a check .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990276/double-height-of-selected-row-in-listview/57994535#57994535

Comment: Hi Lucas, your code works. Thank you so much. But the transition seems not very smooth. It seems it's a bit heavy.

Comment: If it's a big list with lots of cells to hide or show, it becomes unusable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207958/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-hong-wang).